# Question about finitely generated k-algebras.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I have a question on Milne's Algebraic geometry, p.194, Lemma 9.3

[image]

I can't understand the underlined statement. I tried by using several method, but I stucked.

My attempt : Let $m=0$. Then $f$ is of the form $a_{0}$ and we have situation

$$ 0 \neq a_{0} \in \mathfrak{a} \varsubsetneq A[T]  \ (\because B \neq 0)$$

and $\alpha(a_{0}) \neq 0$. If $a_{0}$ is unit in $A$, then $ A[T] =(a_{0}) \subseteq \mathfrak{a} \varsubsetneq A[T] $, which is contradiction.

Is this argument correct? If not, then is there any other method to prove $m \ge 1$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key point is to understand what is $\mathfrak{a}$. We have a surjective homomorphism $A[T]\to B$ which sends $T\to t$. And $\mathfrak{a}$ is the kernel of this homomorphism. So it is clear that a nonzero constant polynomial can't belong to $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I have not asked what is $\mathfrak{a}$. It was better to ask the defitnition of $\mathfrak{a}$. Anyway thanks ! :)

Comment: Well, that's the key to understanding why $m\geq 1$. A constant polynomial just can't belong to $\mathfrak{a}$.